# OpenGL - Depth test doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl

I am leanring OpenGL and at the moment I learn how to add the 3rd dimension. I want to make a Cube but only one of its sides is not transparent:

[image: Current front side is transparent]

[image: Blue side is not transparent]

My draw-function looks like this:

```
void draw()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH);

    glUseProgram(program);

    // The attributes are like they have to be, nothing wrong here
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboCube);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributePosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        attributePosition,
        3,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        sizeof(attributes),
        (GLvoid *)offsetof(attributes, position)
    );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        attributeColor,
        3,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        sizeof(attributes),
        (GLvoid *)offsetof(attributes, color)
    );

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboCube);
    int size;
    glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size / sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attributePosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attributeColor);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

and my tick-function (which is called 40 times per second) looks like this:

```
void tick()
{
    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(0, 0, -4));
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, -2, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, -4), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, WIDTH / (float) HEIGHT, 0.1f, 10.0f);
    glm::mat4 daRealMvp = projection * view * model; // 9gaggers will get this

    // adding some rotation so i can see why the cube looks strange
    float angle = glfwGetTime();
    daRealMvp = daRealMvp * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1), angle, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformMvp, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(daRealMvp));
}
```

If I remove `glEnable(GL_DEPTH);` (or move it to another line) or change `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` to `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` nothing changes, so I thought there is a problem with clearing the depth-buffer, but I don't know what it is.

So, what can I do to get a nice cube? :)

EDIT1:

funny thing is, the blue face (which is not transparent) isnt the one on the front (where all vertices have positive Z), its the the one on the right (where all vertices have a positive X).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

instead of

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
```

at the third line.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. This was the one thing that was wrong. That's what I don't like at OpenGL.. I didn't get any errors or something it just silently didn't work ^^

Comment: Just wondering, why is the blue face always drawn even if another one has the vertices with the positive Z?

Comment: I can't tell :), but for errors you can always check glGetError using a macro or even better setup a debug context, good luck

Comment: I'm used to work with exceptions... it feels very strange to check `glCheckError` :D

Comment: @Exhauzt: Don't rely on exceptions, not even in languages that have them. Exceptions should be reserved for conditions its hard or impossible to recover from. For everything else use error codes. I'm not going into the details why exceptions are a bad way of reporting errors, you just have to take my word on it.